# Кто такой воробей

Tags: семантика

Как вы думаете, какой смысл имеет слово *воробей*?

Уточню. Меня интересуют не праформы слова, а то значение, которое заложено в имени птички и  тот образ, который возникает в голове при произнесении слова *воробей*. Семантика, а не этимология...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

О каком воробье думаешь, такой и смысл:

1. Полевой воробей.
2. Домашний воробей.
3. Символ скромности, бедности, незначительности (воробьи приносились в жертву людьми самыми бедными (Лев 14:4), так как два из них продавались за ассарий (Мф 10:29), а пять — за два ассария (Лк 12:6)).
   [БЭАН / **Воробей**](http://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%AD%D0%90%D0%9D/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B9)

(А у греков являлся атрибутом Афродиты и отождествлялся с Лесбией, в Японии олицетворяет лояльность. — Википедия.)

4. Капитан Джек Воробей (англ. Captain Jack Sparrow) — главный персонаж киносерии «Пираты Карибского моря».
5. «Воробьями» на сленге в Гонконге называют карманников: Фильм "Воробей" (Man jeuk Sparrow, Cultured Bird, Johnnie To's Sparrow Mancheuk).
   [**Воробей — фильм** | world-art.ru](http://www.world-art.ru/cinema/cinema.php?id=24207)
6. Воробей — вольный сталкер с завода «Росток». Счастливый обладатель уникального ствола — бесшумной Коры-919. Любитель дуэлей.
   [**Воробей**](http://ru.stalker.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B9)
7. Аня Воробей (наст. имя Любовь Маматова, молодая певица. Выпустила несколько альбомов в поп-музыке).
8. Воробей Елена (Елена Яковлевна Лебенбаум, российская эстрадная актриса и пародистка).

А вот "вора бей" — уже не слово, а два — омофон слова "воробей".

Происхождение праслав. ***vorbьjь** говорит, что оно образовано от звукоподражания **vorb*, так что смысл — что-то ворчащее.

Comment: Людмила, Вы сказали почти то же самое, что и я имел в виду! Позже свой ответ или коммент напишу.

Comment: А еще Эдит Пиаф — «воробышек Парижа»

Answer (score 1):

Как очень точно замечено в Википедии, воробей смел, хитёр, назойлив и вороват (Жизнь 
заставляет и люди научили). ОН умён, памятлив, отвечает доброжелательным отношением. 
Как бы я не был одет, воробьи узнают сразу. Бывает, что они стремятся "раскрутить" 
меня на дополнительную кучку пшена, делая вид, что не замечают, куда сыплю первую. 
Отдельные птички садятся иногда буквально под ноги в стороне от общей кормушки, 
выпрашивая "эксклюзив". При мне они обычно не ссорятся, не галдят, голоса их 
становятся мелодичнее. Воробьи, видимо, умеют разговаривать.
В местах с развитым сельским хозяйством воробьи могут наносить некоторый урон 
урожаю. Но точно также и другие птицы - голуби, вороны и др. И, в любом случае, 
отлавливая вредных насекомых при выкармливании птенцов, воробей, по меньшей мере, 
компенсирует приносимый им урон. 
Человек повинен в том, что занял жизненное пространство диких животных. И не 
унимается. То есть, себя должен ограничивать каждый сознательный индивидуум.
Белорусское "верабей" могло быть заимствовано в русский и переосмыслено как"вора 
бей", но не везде и не всеми. 
Что могут означать похожие по звучанию названия воробья в других славянских языках?
Неужели и там никто ничего не знает?
укр. горобець
болг. врабче, врабец и т. д.

Comment: For behemothus:
Спасибо! Трудно читать по-гречески, тем более говорить, делать записи. Завидую Вашему умению. 
Подспудно моя мысль была о том: если уж воробьиное "имя" во многих славянских языках идёт от одного корня, возможно ли, всё-таки, найти в любом из этих языков осмысленный перевод, принять его за основу. Не обязательно же пыжиться, кичиться по поводу того, что мы русские (или мы, украинцы и т. д.) изобрели слово "воробей" ("горобец" и т. д.).
Хотя вопрос темы был поставлен с предупреждением " Семантика, а не этимология", одно от другого отделить удастся ли?

Comment: Т. е., возможно, постановка вопроса некорректна, 
проблему надо решать синтетически, используя все возможные пути.
В болгарском языке одно из слов, которыми зовут воробья, переводится как "забияка".
Точно также, во французском есть значение слова с возможными переводами: Пьеро, простофиля, придурок (Как бы, человек из народа, "серенькая" птичка, что и есть на самом деле).
В латыни passer marinus (воробей заморский) - страус. Это может говорить о том, что римляне любили пошутить и считали воробья забавной птичкой.

Comment: Считаю, что найти исходное значение слова, которое во всех славянских звучит и пишется примерно одинаково, возможно.
Воробей и трудяга, и проказник-воришка, и половой разбойник.
В одном из романов Зигфрида Ленца хитроумный грек раскрашивал пойманных воробьишек во все цвета радуги и продавал их как райских птичек туристам из Европы и северной Америки. Но это к делу не относится, хотя, может быть, используя принципиальную основу пословицы "В огороде бузина, а в Киеве дядька", решить проблему удастся любому энтузиасту.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл в хворобе.  Головная боль и хворь для тех, кто с зерном дело имеет, склевывают.
По английски хвороба-Jubjub bird. Так что слово бей у воробья  не зря. Ну, а про непереводимое идиоматическое слово сами догадайтесь...

Answer (score 0):

Если же вы за этимологию поговорить хотите, то это не смысл, а происхождение. 
Впрочем, басенку про "вора бей" тоже всерьёз не воспринимают.

Этимология

Происходит от праслав. формы *vorbь, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. воробии, русск.-церк.-слав. врабии, русск. воробей, укр. воробе́ць, горобе́ць, горобе́ль, гворобе́ць, белор. веребе́й, воро́бчык, , болг. врабе́ц, сербохорв. вра́бац, словенск. vrábelj, чешск. vrabec, словацк. vrabec, польск. wróbel, в.-луж. wrobel, н.-луж. robel'. Исконнородственно греч. ῥόβιλλος ̇ βασιλίσκος ὄρνις (Гесихий), а также лит. žvìrblis «воробей», латышск. zvir̃bulis — то же. Корень* virb- подвергся, вероятно, в балтийск. языках контаминации со словом на ž- (латышск. z), ср. латышск. zvipuris «воробей», zvīgurs — то же, zvañdzina^t «звенеть, звонить»; см. звягу́. Сомнительна гипотеза Шахматова о праслав. *γvorb-. Из прарусск.* ворбии заимств. фин. varpunen — то же.Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера;
(Вики)